# Docker Nginx worker process runs as non-root user but still can access a file owned by root

Tags: linux, docker, nginx, drupal, permissions

I am using docker nginx official image https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/master/stable/alpine/Dockerfile . I run it like `docker exec -it -v drupal:/var/www/drupal/web`

**web** is my document root. When I cd into `/var/www/drupal/web` and `ls -al` I see the file permissions are like below. Everything is owned by root while the **nginx worker process** is owned by **nginx** a non-root user. But when go to localhost:80 I can access my website. How is this possible ? How can nginx user access the files owned by root? Is there any security issue ?

```
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          1025 Oct 18 23:39 .csslintrc
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           357 Oct 18 23:39 .editorconfig
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           151 Oct 18 23:39 .eslintignore
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            41 Oct 18 23:39 .eslintrc.json
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          3858 Oct 18 23:39 .gitattributes
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          2314 Oct 18 23:39 .ht.router.php
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          7866 Oct 18 23:39 .htaccess
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root           385 Oct 18 23:39 autoload.php
drwxr-xr-x   44 root     root          1408 Oct 18 23:38 core
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           549 Oct 18 23:39 index.php
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root            96 Oct 18 23:39 modules
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root            96 Oct 18 23:39 profiles
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          1594 Oct 18 23:39 robots.txt
drwxr-xr-x    6 root     root           192 Oct 18 23:39 sites
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root            96 Oct 18 23:39 themes
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           848 Oct 18 23:39 update.php
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          4555 Oct 18 23:39 web.config
```

Nginx container process are given below:

```
17     1 nginx    S    14344   1%   0   0% nginx: worker process
 1     0 root     S    13896   1%   0   0% nginx: master process
```

Answer (score 2):

In the `ls -l` listing, the `r` in the eighth column means the file is world-readable; the directories with `x` in the tenth column can also be accessed by anyone.  From what you've posted, nothing is accessing any content it doesn't have the right to.

(The world-writeable `autoload.php` is probably dangerous, if it lets anyone who has shell access to the system write arbitrary code that your Web server will run.)

Comment: So to make a website secure, only we should care about if the files thats is getting exposed to world via nginx should not have write access ??

Comment: That's...a complicated question.  You might not want your `.gitattributes` file to be served by nginx, for instance, and even if you have the file permissions correct there can be bugs in your script that compromise things.